# Joins in dynamodb tables

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

can we perform joins on DynamoDB table? If yes then please provide any sample for node js. here is my sample query.

```
SELECT M.*,MH.*,MP.* FROM MERCHANT AS M JOIN MERCHANT_HIERARCHY AS MH ON M.MERCHANT_ID=MH.SUB_MERCHANT_IDJOIN MERCHANT ON MH.MERCHANT_ID=MP.MERCHANT_IDWHERE M.USERNAME='THIS' AND M.PASSWORD='THIS' AND M.STATUS='ACTIVE'
```

if you are not unable to understand this query you can use any table for one to one and one to many join example.

Comment: No. Dynamo is a NoSQL database, you can't do an SQL select statement like the one in your question on a NoSQL databases.

Comment: @PatrickHund can we manage one to one mapping in single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon DynamoDB is **NoSQL database**, often commonly referred to as a Document Store because it can store complex fields as JSON objects.

- It cannot be used with SQL
- Tables cannot be joined
- Fields can't be mapped between tables

**There are exceptions.** For example, **Hive on Amazon EMR** can connect to DynamoDB and run SQL against data in DynamoDB and can even join tables between DynamoDB and other data sources. However, this is not a model that would normally be used to access data in DynamoDB.